# You prove that vertex cover reduces to some problem A, does that mean that A is NP-Complete?

Tags: np-complete, np

My question is essentially the title. Let's say you have some random problem A. You prove that Vertex Cover (which is NP-Complete) reduces to A. You know nothing else about A besides that Vertex Cover reduces to it. Does that mean that A is NP-Complete? Or because we don't know if P = NP, we technically don't know if A is in NP or P?

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with the relevant definitions:

> A problem $A$ is NP-complete if:
>
> - $A$ is in NP, and
> - $A$ is NP-hard.
>
> A problem $A$ is NP-hard if for every problem $B$ in NP, there is a polytime reduction from $B$ to $A$.

Using these definitions, you can prove the following result:

> If a problem $B$ is NP-hard and there is a reduction from $B$ to $A$, then problem $A$ is also NP-hard.

Applying this to your problem, if there is a reduction from vertex cover to $A$, then $A$ is NP-hard. If $A$ is also in NP, then it is furthermore NP-complete. Whether P=NP or not has absolutely no bearing on this.

Note that there are NP-hard problems which are provably not in NP. For example, the halting problem is NP-hard, but is known not to be in NP.

Comment: You say 'if A is also in NP'. Assuming the ONLY thing we know about A is that vertex cover reduces to A, is this enough information to KNOW that A is in NP (and that it is NP-complete?)

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you show a *deterministic polynomial-time many-one* reduction from Vertex Cover to problem A, *and problem A is in NP*, then A is NP-complete. By definition, if A is NP-complete, that means that A is in NP and every problem in NP has a deterministic polynomial-time many-one reduction to A.

If P = NP, then every problem in NP can be solved in deterministic polynomial time. This means that every problem A in NP that has at least one accepting instance and at least one rejecting instance is NP-complete, because every problem B in NP can be polynomial-time many-one reduced to A by just solving B in polynomial time and choosing the appropriate A instance to return.

Answer (score 0):

Yuval Filmus's answer is absolutely correct, but let me answer your questions a bit more directly.

> Let's say you have some random problem A. You prove that Vertex Cover (which is NP-Complete) reduces to A. You know nothing else about A besides that Vertex Cover reduces to it. Does that mean that A is NP-Complete?

No -- it means that A is *NP-Hard,* but not necessarily *NP-complete.* In particular, A might not be in NP. A could be much "harder", for example, exponential time or undecidable.

> Or because we don't know if P = NP, we technically don't know if A is in NP or P?

Whether P = NP doesn't matter here; what's important is that you only showed A is NP-hard, not that it is NP-complete. Remember, NP-complete means two requirements: first, A is in NP, and second, A is NP-hard.

---

By the way, even if P = NP, that doesn't mean that problems can't be NP-hard or NP-complete. Vertex Cover, for example, would still be NP-complete; it would just also be in P, so the notion of NP-completeness would not be as interesting or useful.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that a problem being NP-hard doesn't mean that it is in NP.